# Twitter trending topics RSS feed for specific country

Tags: twitter, rss

Is there any way to generate Twitter rss feed URL for trending tweets in a specific country? For example, I would like to generate rss feed with the most discussed topics on Twitter in Germany. Can this be done and how?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Use this Twitter API https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/trends/place to get the trends and then generate the RSS feed yourself.

It will require a WOEID (http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/) which is for Germany is 23424829 (https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/6942)